# How to post image(BufferedImage object) on Facebook using restFB API

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

- Have an Image as BufferedImage object.
- Need to post it on Facebook using the restFB API.

I do not prefer the method of first saving the object in some external format and then publishing it as a `Binaryattachment` using restFB. Is there any direct way of doing this? I mean I need a method in which I can give the `BufferedImage` object as argument and it gets posted using `restFB`.

Answer (score 0):

The RestFB BinaryAttachment accepts a byte array (http://restfb.com/javadoc/com/restfb/BinaryAttachment.html), so you can convert your BufferedImage in some byte array and you should be ready to publish.